# Remove property from Json Object c#

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON:

```
{
"scbs_currentstatus": "",
  "scbs_primaryissue": "",
  "_umb_id": "Test",
  "_umb_creator": "Admin",
  "_umb_createdate": "0001-01-01 00:00:00",
  "_umb_updatedate": "0001-01-01 00:00:00",
  "_umb_doctype": "Test",
  "_umb_login": "Test",
  "_umb_email": "Test",
  "_umb_password": {
    "newPassword": "Test",
    "oldPassword": null,
    "reset": null,
    "answer": null
  },
  "_umb_membergroup": {
    " User": false,
    "Line User": true,
    "Callback User": false,
    "Su User": false,
    },
  "umbracoMemberComments": "Test",
  "umbracoMemberFailedPasswordAttempts": ""

}
```

how would i remove a specifiec property within the node such as "newPassword" inside "_umb_password".

I have result.Property("_umb_id").Remove(); but it removes the node.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how are you reading/writing json but if you are using Json.net. You can do like this

```
class YouClassName
{
    .....
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string newPassword{get;set;}

}
```

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm

Comment: Thanks but i need to remove properties based on some conditions in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with Linq

```
var myJson =  JArray.Parse(json);
myJson.Descendants()
    .OfType<JProperty>()
    .Where(attr => attr.Name.StartsWith("newPassword"))
    .ToList();
    .ForEach(attr => attr.Remove());
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I may have multiple child elements that have the same property within it. How can i specifically only select one child, like _umb_password -> newPassword